# Android sdk package not installing

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-manager

[image]I have downloaded android studio during the first launch I got an error something like check proxy etc, but after that AS runs well, when I got into Android sdk manager to install packages, available packages are not clickable I can not check them to install package.

Comment: Can you post an image or screen shot of your SDK Manager?

Comment: Yeah I can, but I have internet issues right now, the other thing I want to tell you is that in sdk manager I have also a warning that says about whitespaces etc.

Comment: This warning means that you SDK path contains white spaces. It's better to remove those by changing the names of folders in which your SDK is. But the issue you are facing is not because of that.

Comment: now i have uploaded the image, you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for your issue, try these. Hope one of them will work:

1. Make sure you have space in the drive where your SDK is placed.
2. Remove whitespaces from path, or create another folder in any drive and replace the path of Sdk in Android Studio. But make sure new path doesn't contain whitespaces. (eg. "E/sdk").
3. If the solution mentioned above doesn't work for you then copy the path that Android Studio in showing for Sdk and paste it in file manager. It will take you to the SDK folder. There you will see "SDKManager.exe" file. Open that exe file as Administrator, it will open SDK stand-alone manager. It'll let you install all platforms.

Hope it will work!